# Il significato di "recare in trionfo"

Tags: meaning

Buona sera.

C'è un brano da Luigi Pirandello nel romanzo *Il fu Mattia Pascal*:

> Ma come, signor Meis, se alla lampa nostra manca l’olio sacro che alimentava quella del Poeta? Molti ancora vanno nelle chiese per provvedere dell’alimento necessario le loro lanternucce. Sono, per lo più, poveri vecchi, povere donne, a cui mentì la vita, e che vanno innanzi, nel bujo dell’esistenza, con quel loro sentimento acceso come una lampadina votiva, cui con trepida cura riparano dal gelido soffio degli ultimi disinganni, chè duri almeno accesa fin là, fino all’orlo fatale, al quale s’affrettano, tenendo gli occhi intenti alla fiamma e pensando di continuo: — Dio mi vede! — per non udire i clamori della vita intorno, che suonano ai loro orecchi come tante bestemmie. — Dio mi vede... — perché lo vedono loro, non solamente in sé, ma in tutto, anche nella loro miseria, nelle loro sofferenze, che avranno un premio, alla fine. Il fioco, ma placido lume di queste lanternucce desta certo invidia angosciosa in molti di noi; a certi altri, invece, che si credono armati, come tanti Giove, del fulmine domato dalla scienza, e, in luogo di quelle lanternucce, **recano in trionfo** le lampadine elettriche, ispira una sdegnosa commiserazione.

Il verbo "recare" vuol dire "portare". Comunque mi chiedo cosa vuol dire "recano in trionfo": le portano con sé, figurativamente, oppure semplicemente le lodano? Mi pare che sia il primo significato, ma non sono sicuro perché il verbo "recare" sembra essere invece spesso usato in un senso più figurato.

Mi potreste aiutare? Grazie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'espressione è usata in senso figurato, e come hai notato, *recare* qui è sinonimo di *portare*:

> *portare qualcuno in trionfo*, sollevarlo in alto sulle braccia, per festeggiarlo, specialmente dopo una vittoria sportiva;
>
> (*Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/portare/)*)

Il senso del brano è che alcune persone preferiscono esaltare ("recare in trionfo") le conquiste della Scienza (qui rappresentate dalle lampadine elettriche), piuttosto che restare legati ai riti del passato, come le lampadine votive ad olio.

Ironicamente, tutte le lampadine votive che ho visto recentemente sono elettriche (anche perché il fumo delle lampadine ad olio rovina i muri), ma questo non era il caso anche solo dieci anni fa, figuriamoci al tempo in cui scriveva Pirandello.

Comment: Non avrei immaginato di ricercare sulla pagina di "portare", molte grazie !

Comment: @Evgeniy Ad essere onesti, ho provato "portare" dopo aver cercato sotto la voce "trionfo" in almeno quattro dizionari... Ed io conoscevo l'espressione :)